# Why is Chef Provisioning not honoring my availability zone?

Tags: chef-infra, provisioning, chef-recipe

For some reason Chef Provisioning is not honoring my availability zone in this recipe:

```
context = ChefDK::ProvisioningData.context

target_port = context.opts.port

require 'chef/provisioning'

machine 'amx01' do
    machine_options :bootstrap_options => {
                        :key_name => 'chef',
                        :flavor_id => 't2.small',
                        :vpc_id => 'vpc-4de3dy17',
                        :subnet_id => 'subnet-47721f1e',
                        :availability_zones => ["us-east-1c"],
                        :image_id => 'ami-06c4cb11', 
                        :security_group_ids => ["sg-c35170c0", "sg-e7r05162"],
                        :associate_public_ip_address => "true"
},
convergence_options: context.convergence_options
converge(true)
action(context.action)
end
```

This should go to us-east-1c but it always goes to us-east-1d. Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`availability_zones` does not exist for machines. You need to set `availability_zone` (singular), and pass in a String, not an Array, and it needs to be nested under placement, as documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/EC2/Resource.html#create_instances-instance_method).

Comment: Thank you! Did not realize that lined up with the actual aws sdk syntax!

Comment: I think it's only documented on Github, not the regular Chef docs. Not exactly ideal.